# Cross Join over Linq XML and Linq Objects lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a xml file with that content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<packages>
  <package productnumber="123">
    <stpos>
      <pid>345</pid>
      <vat>10</vat>
    </stpos>
    <stpos>
      <pid>678</pid>
      <vat>20</vat>
    </stpos>
  </package>
  <package productnumber="246">
    <stpos>
      <pid>81012</pid>
      <vat>5</vat>
    </stpos>
    <stpos>
      <pid>141618</pid>
      <vat>2</vat>
    </stpos>
  </package>
</packages>
```

then I still have a product list:

```
var productList = new List<Product>
{
    new Product {ProductNumber = "123" },
    new Product {ProductNumber = "345" },
    new Product {ProductNumber = "678" },
    new Product {ProductNumber = "246" },
    new Product {ProductNumber = "81012" },
    new Product {ProductNumber = "Nothing" },
};
```

I want that for check each package`s productnumber and its pid`s existance in the productList. If its true then return those package.

In my sample above:

I want to *return package with productnumber 123* because all 3 product numbers exist in the product list.

The *package with productnumber 246 should not be returned* because only 2 product numbers are contained in the product list, "Nothing" is not contained...

Thats my query:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load("./packages.xml");
    var query = (from package in doc.Descendants("packages").Elements()
                 from p in productList
                 where p.ProductNumber == package.Attribute("productnumber").Value &&
                 productList.All(p =>
                 package.Descendants("stpos").Select(x => x.Element("pid").Value).Contains(p.ProductNumber))
                 select package).ToList();
```

My query.Count() is 0 and I do not see why.

Can anyone open my eyes please :-)

Comment: But 345 and 678, which are the pids inside 123, are not contained in `productList`

Comment: That was a typo I corrected now! It still does not work! Count is still ZERO! I also think my cross join - how I use it at the moment - is not correct ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("./packages.xml");
var numbers=productList.Select(p=>p.ProductNumber);
var query= doc.Descendants("package")
              .Where(e=>numbers.Contains( (string)e.Attribute("productnumber")) && 
                         e.Descendants("stpos").All(p=>numbers.Contains((string)p.Element("pid"))) );
```

Comment: Hm... you are not using the .Value on the Element. With your string casted code I get ZERO count. Ok I got it working now! => Its Descendants("package") and yo u have to do p.Element("pid").Value, Please add that to your solution :-)

Comment: But "ProductName" is not an string property?, casting will also get the value of the element/attribute

Comment: pid, productNumber is a string, both!

Comment: `p.Element("pid").Value` is the same of `(string)p.Element("pid")`.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right, then I was confused by some other stuff :-)